# Why can't I get this entity code to display correctly in a browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm trying to code a UK Pound symbol to be written to a document by JavaScript, but it's code is not being translated and is instead displayed as entered.

See this JSBin http://jsbin.com/orocox/1/edit

This is the JavaScript:

```
$("#price").text('&pound; 1.99');
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="price"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:
'&pound(;) 1.99'

*Note that the parenthesis around the ';' are added by me to prevent the entity code from being translated on StackOverflow, but they do not exist in the actual output.

The result I want is:
'£ 1.99'.

Comment: Try this: `$("#price").html('&pound; 1.99');`

Comment: @MikeW Tried that. It didn't work either.

Comment: It works on your `jsbin`

Comment: @MikeW my mistake. That's where I tried it earlier and it didn't work, but I guess it didn't update or something. You're right and I apologise, it does work.

Comment: No problem - I'm glad you have a solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use unicode instead: [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/izerap/1/edit)

```
$("#price").text('\u00A3 1.99');
```

explanation: the `&pound;` is an html entity and is not processed as normal text. but unicode works for any text. since you are using `text` it is processed as a string not an html.

check this page's encoding reference : **[here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#price").html('&pound; 1.99');` instead.

Comment: actually it should work too, as it responds to html entities because he is using html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the character itself:

```
$("#price").text('£ 1.99');
```

This is good for the readability of your code. How you type “£” depends on your editing environment. E.g., on Windows, you can produce it by typing Alt 0163 if you cannot find any more convenient way (depending on keyboard, keyboard layout, and editor being used).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it was displayed as a question mark inside a small black diamond shape. I'm using Linux and don't have the pound sign on my keyboard either, so I accessed the insert special character option from Thunderbird's Compose window and copied it to the clipboard then pasted it into the source, which had the result I described.

Comment: Then the character encoding of the file you created is not actually `<meta charset=utf-8 />`, despite the tag saying so, or that tag overridden with HTTP headers. This is a serious risk, since it probably implies that any non-Ascii character that you might intentionally or unintentionally insert would go wrong. See http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've reviewed it and made the relevant changes.